# C3374: can't take address of 'function' unless creating delegate instance

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr

I am having difficulty using a thirdparty library registration function to register a callback.  I am writing in C++ CLI, and accessing a library written in C or C++.

What does the above compiler error mean?

this is the registration function as defined by the vendor:

```
MYCO int WINAPI MyCo_Device_Register_CallbackFunc(LPVOID func, LPVOID lpParam, DWORD mask);
```

this is the callback as defined by the vendor:

```
typedef void (CALLBACK* MyCo_Device_CallbackProc)(DWORD ddStatus, LPVOID lpParam);
```

My callback function:

```
public ref class Device 
{
    void CallBackFunc(DWORD ddStatus, LPVOID lpParam) {};
}
```

My call (which fails):

```
MyCo_Device_Register_CallbackFunc((LPVOID) Device::CallBackFunc, nullptr, 0xFFFF);
```

Comment: duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822526/how-do-i-register-a-callback-in-a-c-library-from-my-cli-wrapper

Comment: that question has been deleted

Comment: I've expanded my answer down below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I had to wager a guess, you're trying to taken the address of a MANAGED function and pass it as a NATIVE function pointer. That won't work at all. Either write a native bridge (harder and probably no advantage), or (and this is the easier approach), create a delegate and use [Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx). Don't forget that the delegate has to stay alive for the duration that the native code expects to call back, so you most likely need to store it somewhere.

Oh, and all functions inside a ref class or value class are managed functions, in case that wasn't clear.

[EDIT] Expanding answer to cover questions in comments. The first step is to create a matching delegate. For the function you provided, it's going to look like this:

```
public delegate void CallbackFuncDelegate(DWORD ddStatus, LPVOID lpParam);
```

Then, you'll need to create one:

```
CallbackFuncDelegate del = gcnew CallbackFuncDelegate(CallbackFunc);
```

And as noted previously, you should store that IN your class as a member in order to make sure it doesn't vanish. Lastly, you need to get the function pointer and pass it down:

```
MyCo_Device_Register_CallbackFunc((MyCo_Device_CallbackProc) Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(del).ToPointer(), 0, 0);
```

I think that covers everything. All you need is using namespace System; and you should be fine.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head.  how does the code that you suggest look like, and what includes do I need?

Comment: and how do I ensure that I am keeping the delegate alive so that it doesn't get collected (lifetime management)

Comment: I made the following changes: 1. ^ missing in delegate creation 2. & missing when gcnew-ing the delegate CallbackFuncDelegate^ del = gcnew CallbackFuncDelegate(&H8Device::BtnCallBackFunc);

Comment: one more problem that I cannot solve: void Device:CallbackFunc(DWORD, LPVOID): the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (DWORD,LPVOID)'       Alexy suggested making this a static (which allows it compile), but with a static, I don't have access to any of the class's data.

Comment: As the example for this error on msdn shows http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5408cs95(VS.80).aspx , you can pass in a reference to your device when creating the delegate:
   CallbackFuncDelegate ^ del = gcnew CallbackFuncDelegate(device, &Device::CallbackFunc);

Then it doesn't need to be a static method.

Comment: Additional good example in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c320cx3h.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Also note if the delegated function isn't static you need to pass the instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/9809281/1236401

Answer (score 0):

your callback func is a member -- pointer to members and pointers to functions are different things.

Even in Promit's solution:

```
CallbackFuncDelegate(CallbackFunc)
```

CallbackFunc should not be class member

You can write simply

```
public ref class Device 
{
    static void CallBackFunc(DWORD ddStatus, LPVOID lpParam) {};
}
```

and then use

```
Device::CallBackFunc
```

Comment: your suggestion did fix the compile issue, but it seems strange that I now have a static method that has no access to private data (can't do anything).  I wonder if this will work

Comment: First of all -- it has access to **static** private data. 
Second -- you can create some kind of Singleton 8). Use this pattern directly -- or create delegate which will have static function and static pointer to object.

And just to clarify about pointer-to-member issue:
you can read some intro here 
http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=142

To make the long story short -- your initial (non-static) callback-func needs "this" pointer -- that's why pointer-to-member is different -- you can use it only if you have an object

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Changing my class to be a singleton in order to use callbacks somehow doesn't feel quite right.

Comment: Singleton solution is for the case when you can have only one device.
Just in case -- anyway, since you need static pointer -- you can have only one Device getting callbacks (until you can pass user-data which will be passed back to your callback)

Comment: Just looked again through the code
MYCO int WINAPI MyCo_Device_Register_CallbackFunc(LPVOID func, LPVOID lpParam, DWORD mask);
lpParam can be just the thing you need. Look in documentation -- if this is the same lpParam that is passed to your callback, you can insert pointer to needed Device ;-)

Comment: No need for singletons, statics or even pinning, you **can** use a member function of your managed class as the callback, but you must use the delegate constructor which takes 2 arguments; for the first argument, pass in your 'this' pointer of the managed object, and for the second argument you must qualify the function name like so: `my_del = gcnew MyDelegate(this, &MyClass::callback)`. You can then get your native-callable function pointer via `Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(my_del).ToPointer()`

Comment: @Alexey: you may wish to edit the answer above to reflect my comment, since your posting, as it currently stands, makes some incorrect statements.

Comment: One more thing... if your callback signature is `void` returning `void`, you don't need to define your own `Delegate` type to match your function, you can just use `System::Action` instead.