# Create a public string in C++ CLI

Tags: .net, string, class, events, c++-cli

I have 2 classes.
I use `System::Speech::recognition` in C++/CLI.
Now, I have the event handler at the end:

```
recognizer->SpeechRecognized += gcnew EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
```

I also have the callback function:

```
void sre_SpeechRecognized(Object^ sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^ e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

This throws me an Error:

```
Invalid Delegate initializer -- Function is no Member of a managed-class
```

Any idea why, and any idea how to fix it?

And another (related) question:

`sre_SpeechRecognized()` should assign the result value to a String variable.

Now: That string variable is declared in the same class:
`public: String^ res_SR = ""`
and C++ CLI hates me for that aswell.
(Somehow I don't have `std::string`, only `System::String`...)

Any idea on how to fix those 2 problems?

EDIT (In case my code snippet with the error in it helps):

```
ref class tsapi
{
    void recogn_speech() {
        SpeechRecognizer^ recognizer = gcnew SpeechRecognizer();

        Choices^ commands_vc = gcnew Choices();
        commands_vc->Add(gcnew array<String^> { "Move", "To" });

        GrammarBuilder^gb = gcnew GrammarBuilder();
        gb->Append(commands_vc);

        Grammar^ g = gcnew Grammar(gb);
        recognizer->LoadGrammar(g);

        // Register Event
        recognizer->SpeechRecognized += gcnew EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
    }

    void sre_SpeechRecognized(Object^ sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^ e)
    {
        String^ res = e->Result->Text->ToString();
    }
};
```

Comment: Alright, I got the "Public string" fixed...
I just needed to do it like this:

`ref class tsapi
{
public:
    static String^ a = "";
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net doesn't have the concept of 'global functions'. *Everything* must be contained in a class. The C++/CLI compiler will take some methods & variables that look like globals, and stick them as static members in a special class, but apparently not everything. Take the code where you're doing `recognizer->SpeechRecognized += ...`, stick it in a class (`ref class`, so it's a managed class), and put `sre_SpeechRecognized` in that class as well.

For the string assignment error, you need to move the assignment from the class definition into a constructor. Like C++, C++/CLI doesn't allow instance variables to be assigned in the class definition. However, I would consider leaving off the explicit assignment: Since you're assigning the empty string, consider just leaving the field as `nullptr`, which .Net ensures by default.

Comment: I did that... `recogn_speech()` and `sre_SpeechRecognized()` are in the same class that is (now, doesn't fix it though) declared with `ref class myClass`

Also, about declaring a variable inside a class, just like a function?
Like, `public String^ a = " ";` but it does not take that (even inside a function)

It shows me the Error is in the `+= gcnew EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionEventArgs^>(sre_SpeechRecognized)` at the `sre_SpeechRecognized` part.

Comment: Now the error message changed though:

`Invalid Delegate initializer -- Function does not match Delegatetype`
which I believe it clearly does, as shown above...

Comment: To declare a class instance field, use the C++ syntax, and initialize it in the constructor, not inline. For the delegate, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9809281/480937

Comment: So basically I have to do it like `recognizer->speechRecognized += gcnew Event Handler<SpeechRecognitionEventArgs>(this, &tsapi::sre_SpeechRecognized)` or something like that?

Comment: Or,, in my case, do I have to write like `EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionEventArgs> callback = gcnew EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionEventArgs>(sre_SpeecgRecognized) recognizer->speechRecognized += callback` (which would just be the same I alredy do.. )